# Convert from PCollection<TableRow> to PCollection<KV<K,V>>

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to extract data from 2 tables in BigQuery, then join it by CoGroupByKey.
Although the output of BigQuery is `PCollection<TableRow>`, `CoGroupByKey` requires `PCollection<KV<K,V>>`.
How can I convert from `PCollection<TableRow>` to `PCollection<KV<K,V>>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CoGroupByKey` needs to know which key to `CoGroup` by - this is the `K` in `KV<K, V>`, and the `V` is the value associated with this key in this collection. The result of co-grouping several collections will give you, for each key, all of the values with this key in each collection.

So, you need to convert both of your `PCollection<TableRow>` to `PCollection<KV<YourKey, TableRow>>` where `YourKey` is the type of key on which you want to join them, e.g. in your case perhaps it might be `String`, or `Integer`, or something else.

The best transform to do the conversion is probably `WithKeys`. E.g. here's a code sample converting a `PCollection<TableRow>` to a `PCollection<KV<String, TableRow>>` keyed by a hypothetical `userId` field of type `String`:

```java
PCollection<TableRow> rows = ...;
PCollection<KV<String, TableRow>> rowsKeyedByUser = rows
    .apply(WithKeys.of(new SerializableFunction<TableRow, String>() {
  @Override
  public String apply(TableRow row) {
    return (String)row.get("userId");
  }
}));
```